# Cannot instantiate the type JavascriptInterface при использовании аннотации @Javascriptinterface

Tags: android, webview

Добрый день. 
Я хочу выполнить `javascript` в `Webview`. Возникли проблемы при создании экземпляра `Javascriptinterface`.  `Target sdk 17`, в документации написано, что нужно только добавить `@Javascriptinterface annotation`. Но получаю ошибку при создании экземпляра `JavascriptInterface -  Cannot instantiate the type JavascriptInterface`

Заранее спасибо.

```
public class RostelecomLoginActivity extends Activity {

WebView webView;
String url;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rostelecom_login);
    Intent webIntent = getIntent();
    String url = webIntent.getStringExtra("url");

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MeWebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);

     Button buttoner = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        buttoner.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                JavascriptInterface javasriptInterface = new JavascriptInterface(RostelecomLoginActivity.this);
                webView.addJavascriptInterface(javasriptInterface, "MyInterface");
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('mA').click();})()");
            }
        });

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Эм. Я правильно понял, что вы пытаетесь инстанциировать интерфейс аннотации? Не удивительно, что компилятор наотрез отказывается работать с этим.

Посмотрите [документацию на метод addJavascriptInterface](http://goo.gl/pTXDn), там приводится пример использования.